# NSTimer Invalidate Is Not Stopping The Timer

Tags: ios, cocoa

```
-(void)DataShow

{   
    for(k=1;k<=10;k++)

     {
         Timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self      
         selector:@selector(LabelUpdateOfTimer) userInfo:nil
         repeats:YES];

         if(k>=10)

        {
            break;

        }

    }
    [Timer invalidate];
    Timer=nil;
}

 -(void)LabelUpdateOfTimer

{

    NSString *temp;
    j=j-0.1;
    temp=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@" %f",j];
    TimerLabel.text=temp;
}
```

Here I created one Timer and when it executed 10 times i want to stop the timer but its not stopping it still going on.

Comment: You're actually creating 10 timers.

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `for` loop you are creating 10 timers, 1 for each increment of `k`.  If you want your timer to fire only 10 times you can track this inside the selector the timer calls.

```
- (void) someMethod
{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    static NSInteger fireCount = 0;

    ++fireCount;

    if(10 <= fireCount)
      [timer invalidate];

    // Do some actual work
}
```

I recommend reading a basic introduction to C control structures to gain a better understanding of the language syntax.

Comment: Thanks Alot sbooth for clearing the concept of timer

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain what I think is going on here. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Imagine the `Timer` variable is a leash. When you spawn a dog, it gets tied to the leash. and when a new one is spawned, the leash is released from the old dog and tied too the new one. The old dog is set free and unless we had tied it to another leash (`variable`) already, we have no way to control or access it from here on.

What you did is fire off 10 NSTimer variables and assigned to the `Timer` variable. Each time a new one is created, the timer previously held by `Timer` is cut loose from the variable but still continues to run in the background I believe.

Then outside the `for` loop, you invalidate the last one (which is still held by the `Timer` variable). The other 9 will continue to run forever, unless you can get a reference to them, and then stop em, which you can't. Get rid of the loop and initiate just one timer. and check the number of times called inside the selector. the code by @sbooth will do the trick.

Hope its clear.

Comment: Nice analogy, save the mental image of spawning a dog!